# Alter this pre-made script to play video?

Tags: jquery, html, video, alter

Can anyone take a look at [this script](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/07/29/thumbnails-navigation-gallery/) and tell me how to alter it so that I can choose between HTML5 video or an image? It would make my day if you could!

Here's the code in case you want it...

```
$(function() {
            //the loading image
            var $loader     = $('#st_loading');
            //the ul element 
            var $list       = $('#st_nav');
            //the current image being shown
            var $currImage  = $('#st_main').children('img:first');

            //let's load the current image 
            //and just then display the navigation menu
            $('<img>').load(function(){
                $loader.hide();
                $currImage.fadeIn(3000);
                //slide out the menu
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $list.animate({'left':'0px'},500);
                },
                1000);
            }).attr('src',$currImage.attr('src'));

            //calculates the width of the div element 
            //where the thumbs are going to be displayed
            buildThumbs();

            function buildThumbs(){
                $list.children('li.album').each(function(){
                    var $elem           = $(this);
                    var $thumbs_wrapper = $elem.find('.st_thumbs_wrapper');
                    var $thumbs         = $thumbs_wrapper.children(':first');
                    //each thumb has 180px and we add 3 of margin
                    var finalW          = $thumbs.find('img').length * 183;
                    $thumbs.css('width',finalW + 'px');
                    //make this element scrollable
                    makeScrollable($thumbs_wrapper,$thumbs);
                });
            }

            //clicking on the menu items (up and down arrow)
            //makes the thumbs div appear, and hides the current 
            //opened menu (if any)
            $list.find('.st_arrow_down').live('click',function(){
                var $this = $(this);
                hideThumbs();
                $this.addClass('st_arrow_up').removeClass('st_arrow_down');
                var $elem = $this.closest('li');
                $elem.addClass('current').animate({'height':'170px'},200);
                var $thumbs_wrapper = $this.parent().next();
                $thumbs_wrapper.show(200);
            });
            $list.find('.st_arrow_up').live('click',function(){
                var $this = $(this);
                $this.addClass('st_arrow_down').removeClass('st_arrow_up');
                hideThumbs();
            });

            //clicking on a thumb, replaces the large image
            $list.find('.st_thumbs img').bind('click',function(){
                var $this = $(this);
                $loader.show();
                $('<img class="st_preview"/>').load(function(){
                    var $this = $(this);
                    var $currImage = $('#st_main').children('img:first');
                    $this.insertBefore($currImage);
                    $loader.hide();
                    $currImage.fadeOut(2000,function(){
                        $(this).remove();
                    });
                }).attr('src',$this.attr('alt'));
            }).bind('mouseenter',function(){
                $(this).stop().animate({'opacity':'1'});
            }).bind('mouseleave',function(){
                $(this).stop().animate({'opacity':'0.7'});
            });

            //function to hide the current opened menu
            function hideThumbs(){
                $list.find('li.current')
                     .animate({'height':'50px'},400,function(){
                        $(this).removeClass('current');
                     })
                     .find('.st_thumbs_wrapper')
                     .hide(200)
                     .andSelf()
                     .find('.st_link span')
                     .addClass('st_arrow_down')
                     .removeClass('st_arrow_up');
            }

            //makes the thumbs div scrollable
            //on mouse move the div scrolls automatically
            function makeScrollable($outer, $inner){
                var extra           = 800;
                //Get menu width
                var divWidth = $outer.width();
                //Remove scrollbars
                $outer.css({
                    overflow: 'hidden'
                });
                //Find last image in container
                var lastElem = $inner.find('img:last');
                $outer.scrollLeft(0);
                //When user move mouse over menu
                $outer.unbind('mousemove').bind('mousemove',function(e){
                    var containerWidth = lastElem[0].offsetLeft + lastElem.outerWidth() + 2*extra;
                    var left = (e.pageX - $outer.offset().left) * (containerWidth-divWidth) / divWidth - extra;
                    $outer.scrollLeft(left);
                });
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the thumbnail click handler, check the `alt` attribute to see what the target source type is and if it is a video format write a video tag instead of an image tag:

```
$list.find('.st_thumbs img').bind('click',function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $loader.show();
    var $currImage = $('#st_main').children('img,video').first();
    var src = $this.attr('alt');
    if (/\.(mp4|ogv)$/i.test(src)) {
        // create video here.  Maybe something like this:
        $("<video>").attr({ src: src }).insertBefore($currImage);
        $loader.hide();
        $currImage.fadeOut(2000,function(){
            $(this).remove();
        });
    }
    else {
        $('<img class="st_preview"/>').load(function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.insertBefore($currImage);
            $loader.hide();
            $currImage.fadeOut(2000,function(){
                $(this).remove();
            });
        }).attr('src',src);
    }
});
```

You'll also need to alter your `$currImage` code to look for video or img.

```
var $currImage = $('#st_main').children('img,video').first();
```

Comment: You are amazing! Thanks! Now what would I use to create the video element @gilly3?

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example that I hope will work. ;-)